# how to do 2 way ssl authentication without using a self signed CA

Tags: authentication, openssl, apache

I have a requirement to set a 2 mutual ssl authentication between our apache and an application. I have purchased a cheap SSL from rapid SSL in order to do this. 
RapidSSL sent a zip folder with

```
CACertificate-1.cer  (RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3)
CACertificate-2.cer  (GeoTrust Global CA)
ServerCertificate.cer (Actual Certificate)
```

But I am stuck at the point where I need to create client's certificate. The [cafesoft.com tutorial](http://www.cafesoft.com/products/cams/ps/docs32/admin/ConfiguringApache2ForSSLTLSMutualAuthentication.html) I am following makes use of the CA's certificate key to generate/sign the client's certificate. Obviously I don't have the CA's Certificate key. How to go about this? Should I just gave up and use a self signed CA or there is a way to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Startssl can sign a client cert for free. They charge to revoke though, FYI

Comment: I doubt it's still free. I actually contacted them I was suggested this https://www.startssl.com/?app=7 since I am not expecting to have more than 50 client this year

Answer (score 1):

The server certificate and the CA certificate used for authenticating your clients are two different things.

First, you need to have your server certificate installed (SSLCertificateFile and SSLCertificateFileKey). You should already have that.

At this point, you have your server presenting his certificate to clients.

Now, you need to generate a CA (self-signed) and tell your Apache instance that this is the CA you want to use for authenticating clients. (SSLCACertificateFile and  SSLVerifyClient require)

You just have to sign your clients csr with your newly created CA.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [client certificate](https://web.archive.org/web/20160307210635/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/kaushal/archive/2012/02/18/client-certificates-v-s-server-certificates.aspx) for each user (or client app if your app is authenticating to the server) that will use mutual auth SSL. You can purchase client certs from an existing CA or create a self-signed CA cert and issue your own certs. If you have many users, purchasing certs can be expensive.